# Ionic v2 - How to know when front-end finish rendering?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How to know when front-end finish rendering?

I mean, you have an Array of something on your backend and
a ngFor on your view.

How can I know when that's finish? I want to know because I need to scroll down when it's finish, and currently it scrolls before it renders.

Here's some code to demostrate the problem:
https://gist.github.com/mtnoronha/e78eba6b610b71f1e72424ed21722be1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a new promise to handle when it has finished loading the messages so you need to scroll to bottom, in your case use it like this:

**YOUR .TS FILE**

```
appendRows(newData){
if(!newData || newData.length == 0)
  return;
  this.myNewPromise().then(res =>{
    if(res){
      this.content.scrollToBottom(0);
    }
  })
}

myNewPromise = (): Promise<boolean> =>{
  return new Promise<boolean>(res){
    if(this.messages){
      let newArray = this.messages.concat(newData);
      this.messages = newArray;
      res(true);
    }else{
      this.messages = newData;
      res(false);
    }
  }
}
```

So your `scrollToBottom`will only fire when `myNewPromise` finishs. In your promise you resolve it and return a boolean, so if there's new message you call the `scrollToBottom`.

If you need to call it either way, just pass a true in both `res` or remove the `if (res)` on the return of `myNewPromise`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi my friend, thank you very much for your answer. You see, the problem is not on the Javascript side. The problem is that Angular uses ngFor to create the view, based on the updated "messages" attribute. So  Angular didnt finish building the view when we call scrollToBottom() on the JS side.

Comment: Even though, I tried your solution just to be sure, and the result was the same :(

Comment: did you took off the ionViewDidEnter? it's also calling the scrollToBottom

Comment: I didnt understand why should I take it off?

Comment: Because you're calling this method when the view load, this is when all components on the screen are loaded, not when every function on your .ts has finished. Maybe this is even why your scrollToBottom fires before all is loaded, and then when the second one fires you can't even notice.

Comment: Even so Gabriel, the problem will persist.

Comment: Well, running your code shows me the behaviour you expect, at least i think it does: It generates a new number, inserts on array then scroll down. Don't know if you're using it with some API to get the data, but with this i can't help you more. Sorry for this and hope you solve it

Comment: I think I wasnt good enough on my explanation. If you run my code, you'll see that you wont see the last added item, it will be hidden because the scroll doesnt really reach the end.